Is there an embedding of singular complex Borel measures into L1(T)?
Let $\mathbb{T}:= \{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z|=1\}$. I read that there is an embedding of $L^1(\mathbb{T})$ into the space $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{T})$ of complex Borel-measures on $\mathbb{T}$, i.e. for all $f \in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ there is a $\mu \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{T})$ such that
\begin{align}
d\mu(e^{it})= f(e^{it}) dt
\end{align}
w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure. My Question is if there is an embedding of singular complex Borel-measures into $L^1(\mathbb{T})$? I.e. if for any singular measure $\mu \in \mathcal{M}(\mathbb{T})$ (w.r.t. Lebesgue measure) there is $f \in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ such that the above equation holds.

NO.  In the form $f(e^{it}),dt$ we get only absolutely continuous measures.
